What type of canopy tree(s) for small commercial property?
The city is requiring I plant a "canopy tree" (potentially a few) on a small commercial property in NW Ohio.  I love trees!  But am concerned about causing problems / pain for myself and neighbors with things like large leaves, berries...etc.
I realize this is a somewhat subjective question, but there have to be better trees for this purpose than maple, oak, sycamore...etc.  Any suggestions greatly appreciated!
I found this definition for a "canopy tree":
https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/canopy-tree

For once a city ordinance I can get behind!  How much room do you have for the trees?  Do they need to fit under power lines, or near a building?

@MackM - great questions.  At least one will have to fit under a power line, though that particular line is quite high (from road to back parking lot light).  I'm not sure yet if the others will be near the building or not, though I understand that changes the answer dramatically.

Buckeye would seem an obvious choice if not for the toxic buckeyes. Really don't see anything wrong with the trees listed. Leaves are unavoidable, avoiding fruit has other negative consequences, primarily a ton of pollen from the short and nasty list of "male street trees" that have become a pollen-dumping blight upon urban landscapes.

Is there a definition of "canopy tree" given, or a list? Generically it's just whatever the tallest tree on a plot is, which can make tall shrubs "canopy trees" if there's nothing taller over them.

Not an expert here, but presumably if you want to look at an evergreen rather then deciduous tree?

@davidgo I would love to, but I don't think they qualify as a canopy tree

Evergreens shed, anyway. Keeping needles through the winter does not mean that needles live forever, as a pile of freshly shed brown needles and hundreds of cones will attest. Pretty sure white pines and giant sequoia are canopy trees by any reasonable definition. If the definition given is not the same one your city uses, it might cause issues with "compliance" which is why you need to know what your city uses for a definition.

Every city I've lived in has a list of "acceptable" trees for planting in the area between the sidewalk and street, or within 8 feet of the street if there's no sidewalk. I would assume that your city would have such a list, especially since they're mandating that you plant at least one tree on your property.
